# Updating an Object with a PUT from a JavaScript array

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, servicestack

I have an array of `ContactCard` object in my JavaScript client, and I need to update one of these objects by making a `PUT` request, with the changed object, to my ServiceStack service, but I'm just so stumped as to how to do it.

This is my DTO definition right now:

```cs
[Route("/directory/contactcard", "PUT")]
public class DirectoryContactCardUpdateRequest : IReturn<bool>
{
    public ContactCard Card { get; set; }
}
```

The client array is populated from a ServiceStack service which returns a `List<ContactCard>`.

I'm trying to pass in the changed `ContactCard` like this, but on the service end every property is just `null`.

```js
$.ajax({
    url: '/RestApi/directory/contactcard',
    type: 'PUT',
    dataType: "json",
    data: { Card: JSON.stringify(e.model) },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (e) {
        alert("Error saving card");
    }
});
```

It looks like ServiceStack is routing properly because I can hit a breakpoint in the service, but why are the properties of the `ContactCard` DTO always all `null`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your request object properties are always `null` because your request data is not correctly formed. You need to change how you are sending your `data` property in the `$.ajax` call:

Currently:

```js
data: { Card: JSON.stringify(e.model) }
```

Should be:

```js
data: JSON.stringify({ Card: e.model })
```

Assuming `e.model` represents a single `ContactCard` object then this should now work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, actually this was the problem

```
var myData = {
ContactCard: e.model
};

$.ajax({
data: JSON.stringify(myData)});
```

Thx for pointing me in the right direction!